# Why is my DTO Null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, nullreferenceexception, dto

I have a few DTOs in a project I am working on. I am using AutoMapper to create the mappings. All of the mappings work except for one of them. I can tell because when retrieving data using LINQ Method Syntax, I am getting Null references. Anyway here is all the code I believe is relevant:

MappingProfile.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using GigHub.Controllers.Api;
using GigHub.Dtos;
using GigHub.Models;

namespace GigHub.App_Start
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationUser, UserDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Gig, GigDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Following, FollowingDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
using AutoMapper;
using GigHub.App_Start;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace GigHub
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");

        }

    }
}
```

Following.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace GigHub.Models
{
    // Alternatively, this class could be called Relationship.
    public class Following
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public string FollowerId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string FolloweeId { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser Follower { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Followee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FollowingDto.cs

```
namespace GigHub.Dtos
{
    public class FollowingDto
    {
        public string FolloweeId { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

FollowingsController.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using GigHub.Dtos;
using GigHub.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace GigHub.Controllers.Api
{
    [Authorize]
    public class FollowingsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public FollowingsController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();    
        }
            //CheckFollow is what I am using to test the Dto
        [HttpGet]
        public bool CheckFollow(FollowingDto dto)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if (_context.Followings.Any(f => f.FolloweeId == userId && f.FolloweeId == dto.FolloweeId))
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Follow(FollowingDto dto)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            if (_context.Followings.Any(f => f.FolloweeId == userId && f.FolloweeId == dto.FolloweeId))
                return BadRequest("Following already exists.");

            var following = new Following
            {
                FollowerId = userId,
                FolloweeId = dto.FolloweeId
            };
            _context.Followings.Add(following);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace GigHub
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var settings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I doubt the tool matters, but I've been using Postman to test my APIs. The only difference I see in this Dto from the others is that the column that Automapper will create the mapping for has the Key and Column Order attributes in the model. I don't understand why that would matter though. I've searched online about this issue already and the solutions didn't help since I am already doing them. Can anyone tell from the code I posted why I can be getting a Null reference? Technically the error in Postman says System.Exception.TargetException but from what I understand it means your LINQ query isn't returning any results.

I know my query works as I've passed in a string FolloweeId that was in my db and the API CheckFollow action worked. So I can only assume that my Dto isn't getting mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I obviously have shown how much of a novice I am at Web APIs. Anyway, I was treating my CheckFollow status as a POST action which it isn't. It is a GET action. And what do GET actions have? Parameters in the URL. So I simply decorated my action parameter as so:

```
public bool CheckFollow([FromUri] FollowingDto dto)
```

This allows the action to pull the parameter from the URL and be passed to the Dto which contained one property of type string anyway. The Dto is no longer null and my actions work.